# WordPress pages are without .php extension

Tags: wordpress, seo

After converting my website to WordPress I did notice that the pages doesn't have the php extensions anymore. Had all my pages index by Google and I've been wondering if lack of .php extension will hurt the SEO. Is there a way to add the .php extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you don't do 301 redirects from your old URLs to your new URLs you will suffer in the rankings as you're essentially starting over. 301 redirects tell Google, and users, your pages have moved and where to. PageRank and page ranking (two different things) are carried over when this is done. Not doing this makes each page look like a new one with no links, etc, and as a result will not rank as well as it previously did.

Comment: Another solutions would be to us .PHP on PAGES plugin